# How do I stop a loop filling the whole array in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add text from two textboxes to an array using a loop, but my code fills every array position with the data, not just one position.

My current code:

```
If collfoldername.Text = "" Or collfolderref.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill all fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To 20
            FolderName(i) = collfoldername.Text
            FolderReference(i) = collfoldername.Text
        Next

    collfoldername.Text = ""
        collfolderref.Text = ""
        collfoldername.Focus()
    End If
```

Any advice?

Comment: You are looping.  If you only want to update one item, don't loop.  If you are trying to *add* something to the collection, use a List<T> instead of an array.

Comment: why you need to insert collfoldername.Text 21 times?

Comment: You have 2 options here, the first and easiest is to follow the recommendation from @LarsTech and use a `List(Of T)` instead and use .Add each time you need to add something. If you must work with an array, then you can use a Static variable to remember the next index you have to use and assign the values from there, incrementing the index after each add operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is assigning all elements in the array from your input.

If you only want to set the next available slot in your array don't use a loop. Instead you need to use a variable to keep track of your position in the array and increment the variable one time per method call:

```
Public Index As Integer
Public FolderName(20) As String
Public FolderReference(20) As String
Sub SetArrayValues()
    If Not Index<FolderName.Length Then
        MsgBox("Array Is Full", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Else If collfoldername.Text = "" Or collfolderref.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill all fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Else
        FolderName(Index) = collfoldername.Text
        FolderReference(Index) = collfoldername.Text
        collfoldername.Text = ""
        collfolderref.Text = ""
        Index +=1
        collfoldername.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub Button1_Click(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SetArrayValues()
End Sub
```

If you want to all more items than your array size would need to resize your array:

```
Public Index As Integer
Public FolderName(20) As String
Public FolderReference(20) As String
Sub SetArrayValues()
    If Not Index<FolderName.Length Then
        ReDim Preserve FolderName(Index)
        ReDim Preserve FolderNameReference(Index)    
    End If
    If collfoldername.Text = "" Or collfolderref.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill all fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Else
        FolderName(Index) = collfoldername.Text
        FolderReference(Index) = collfoldername.Text
        collfoldername.Text = ""
        collfolderref.Text = ""
        Index +=1
        collfoldername.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub Button1_Click(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SetArrayValues()
End Sub
```

Another option is to use the `Generic.List(Of T)` and add the values as needed. Using this approach you don't need to keep track of your position in the array.

```
Public FolderName As New Generic.List(Of String)
Public FolderReference As New Generic.List(Of String)
Sub AddValues()

    If collfoldername.Text = "" Or collfolderref.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill all fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Else
        FolderName.Add(collfoldername.Text)
        FolderReference.Add(collfoldername.Text)
        collfoldername.Text = ""
        collfolderref.Text = ""
        collfoldername.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub Button1_Click(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AddValues()
End Sub
```